# Como calcular RankPage de um site

Tags: seo

Ola Pessoal tenho um site e gostaria de saber qual é o RankPage de alguns links. Alguém conhece um site bom para calcular PageRank de uma URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários sites com estes recursos, veja alguns abaixo:

Gosto muito deste: https://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php

Seguem outros

- http://checkpagerank.net/
- https://www.prchecker.info/
- http://www.seocentro.com/tools/search-engines/pagerank.html
- http://smallseotools.com/google-pagerank-checker/
- http://www.cleancss.com/pagerank-checker/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!